# ebpf verifier on 4.9 throws R2 type=inv expected=imm

Tags: linux, ebpf, bpf

I am new to ebpf, and I want to write a CO-RE ebpf program to hook oom_kill_process on kernel 4.9.168 and 4.19. Both servers are of x86_64 arch.

The source code is compiled on kernel 5.10 with clang 12, and loaded with latest cilium/ebpf. When I run the program on kernel 4.9, the verifier throws R2 type=inv expected=imm, while everything is alright on kernel 4.19.

Is there a better way to solve the problem?

The source code:

```c
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>
#include "../oom_kill.h"

extern int LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION __kconfig;
const unsigned ARG_LEN = 64;

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
    __uint(max_entries, 4);
    __type(key, u32);
    __type(value, u32);
} argmap SEC(".maps");

struct {
        __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY);
        __uint(key_size, sizeof(u32));
        __uint(value_size, sizeof(u32));
} events SEC(".maps");

static __always_inline unsigned long read_task_args_len(struct task_struct *task) {
    if(task == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    struct mm_struct *mm = BPF_CORE_READ(task, mm);
    if(mm == NULL) {
            return 0;
    }
    unsigned long arg_end = BPF_CORE_READ(mm, arg_end);
    unsigned long arg_start = BPF_CORE_READ(mm, arg_start);
    if (!arg_end || !arg_start || arg_end <= arg_start) {
        return 0;
    }
    unsigned long len = arg_end - arg_start;
    if(len > ARG_LEN - 1) {
            len = ARG_LEN - 1;
    }
    return len;
}

SEC("kprobe/oom_kill_process")
int BPF_KPROBE(oom_kill_process, struct oom_control *oc, const char *message)
{
    struct data_t data = {};
    data.fpid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
    struct task_struct *ftask = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
    struct task_struct *ttask = (struct task_struct *)BPF_CORE_READ(oc, chosen);
    data.tpid = BPF_CORE_READ(oc, chosen, tgid);
    data.pages = BPF_CORE_READ(oc, totalpages);

    bpf_get_current_comm(&data.fcomm, sizeof(data.fcomm));

    // read arg
    unsigned long flen = read_task_args_len(ftask);
    unsigned long tlen = read_task_args_len(ttask);
    bpf_probe_read_user(data.fprocess, flen, (char *)BPF_CORE_READ(ftask, mm, arg_start));
    bpf_probe_read_user(data.tprocess, tlen, (char *)BPF_CORE_READ(ttask, mm, arg_start));

    bpf_probe_read_kernel(&data.tcomm, sizeof(data.tcomm), BPF_CORE_READ(oc, chosen, comm));

    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &events, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU,
                                    &data, sizeof(data));
    return 0;
}

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

The error msg:

```
0: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -240) = r1
  1: (79) r6 = *(u64 *)(r1 +112)
  2: (b7) r8 = 0
  3: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -8) = r8
  4: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -16) = r8
  5: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -24) = r8
  6: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -32) = r8
  7: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -40) = r8
  8: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -48) = r8
  9: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -56) = r8
  10: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -64) = r8
  11: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -72) = r8
  12: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -80) = r8
  13: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -88) = r8
  14: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -96) = r8
  15: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -104) = r8
  16: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -112) = r8
  17: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -120) = r8
  18: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -128) = r8
  19: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -136) = r8
  20: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -144) = r8
  21: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -152) = r8
  22: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -160) = r8
  23: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -168) = r8
  24: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -176) = r8
  25: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -184) = r8
  26: (85) call 14
  27: (77) r0 >>= 32
  28: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -184) = r0
  29: (85) call 35
  30: (bf) r9 = r0
  31: (b7) r1 = 64
  32: (bf) r7 = r6
  33: (0f) r7 += r1
  34: (bf) r1 = r10
  35: (07) r1 += -216
  36: (b7) r2 = 8
  37: (bf) r3 = r7
  38: (85) call 4
  39: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  40: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -224) = r1
  41: (bf) r1 = r10
  42: (07) r1 += -216
  43: (b7) r2 = 8
  44: (bf) r3 = r7
  45: (85) call 4
  46: (b7) r1 = 2316
  47: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  48: (0f) r3 += r1
  49: (bf) r1 = r10
  50: (07) r1 += -180
  51: (b7) r2 = 4
  52: (85) call 4
  53: (b7) r1 = 56
  54: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -248) = r6
  55: (bf) r3 = r6
  56: (0f) r3 += r1
  57: (bf) r1 = r10
  58: (07) r1 += -216
  59: (b7) r2 = 8
  60: (85) call 4
  61: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  62: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -176) = r1
  63: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -192) = r8
  64: (bf) r2 = r10
  65: (07) r2 += -192
  66: (18) r1 = 0xffff8806ebb00200
  68: (85) call 1
  69: (bf) r1 = r10
  70: (07) r1 += -168
  71: (b7) r2 = 16
  72: (85) call 16
  73: (b7) r6 = 0
  74: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -232) = r9
  75: (15) if r9 == 0x0 goto pc+37
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R6=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R7=inv R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  76: (b7) r1 = 2136
  77: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -232)
  78: (0f) r3 += r1
  79: (bf) r1 = r10
  80: (07) r1 += -216
  81: (b7) r2 = 8
  82: (85) call 4
  83: (79) r9 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  84: (b7) r6 = 0
  85: (15) if r9 == 0x0 goto pc+27
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R6=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R7=inv R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  86: (b7) r1 = 304
  87: (bf) r3 = r9
  88: (0f) r3 += r1
  89: (bf) r1 = r10
  90: (07) r1 += -216
  91: (b7) r2 = 8
  92: (85) call 4
  93: (b7) r1 = 296
  94: (0f) r9 += r1
  95: (79) r7 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  96: (bf) r1 = r10
  97: (07) r1 += -216
  98: (b7) r2 = 8
  99: (bf) r3 = r9
  100: (85) call 4
  101: (b7) r6 = 0
  102: (15) if r7 == 0x0 goto pc+10
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R6=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R7=inv R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  103: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  104: (b7) r6 = 0
  105: (15) if r1 == 0x0 goto pc+7
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R1=inv R6=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R7=inv R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  106: (b7) r6 = 0
  107: (3d) if r1 >= r7 goto pc+5
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R1=inv R6=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R7=inv R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  108: (1f) r7 -= r1
  109: (b7) r1 = 63
  110: (2d) if r1 > r7 goto pc+1
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R1=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R6=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R7=inv,min_value=63 R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  111: (b7) r7 = 63
  112: (bf) r6 = r7
  113: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r10 -224)
  114: (15) if r1 == 0x0 goto pc+33
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R1=inv R6=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R7=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  115: (b7) r1 = 2136
  116: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -224)
  117: (0f) r3 += r1
  118: (bf) r1 = r10
  119: (07) r1 += -216
  120: (b7) r2 = 8
  121: (85) call 4
  122: (79) r9 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  123: (15) if r9 == 0x0 goto pc+24
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R6=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R7=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  124: (b7) r1 = 304
  125: (bf) r3 = r9
  126: (0f) r3 += r1
  127: (bf) r1 = r10
  128: (07) r1 += -216
  129: (b7) r2 = 8
  130: (85) call 4
  131: (b7) r1 = 296
  132: (0f) r9 += r1
  133: (79) r7 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  134: (bf) r1 = r10
  135: (07) r1 += -216
  136: (b7) r2 = 8
  137: (bf) r3 = r9
  138: (85) call 4
  139: (15) if r7 == 0x0 goto pc+8
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R6=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R7=inv R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  140: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  141: (15) if r1 == 0x0 goto pc+6
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R1=inv R6=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R7=inv R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  142: (3d) if r1 >= r7 goto pc+5
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R1=inv R6=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R7=inv R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  143: (1f) r7 -= r1
  144: (b7) r1 = 63
  145: (2d) if r1 > r7 goto pc+1
   R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R1=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R6=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R7=inv,min_value=63 R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  146: (b7) r7 = 63
  147: (bf) r8 = r7
  148: (b7) r9 = 2136
  149: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -232)
  150: (0f) r3 += r9
  151: (bf) r1 = r10
  152: (07) r1 += -200
  153: (b7) r2 = 8
  154: (85) call 4
  155: (b7) r7 = 296
  156: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -200)
  157: (0f) r3 += r7
  158: (bf) r1 = r10
  159: (07) r1 += -216
  160: (b7) r2 = 8
  161: (85) call 4
  162: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  163: (bf) r1 = r10
  164: (07) r1 += -136
  165: (bf) r2 = r6
  166: (85) call 4
  167: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -224)
  168: (0f) r3 += r9
  169: (bf) r1 = r10
  170: (07) r1 += -200
  171: (b7) r2 = 8
  172: (85) call 4
  173: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -200)
  174: (0f) r3 += r7
  175: (bf) r1 = r10
  176: (07) r1 += -216
  177: (b7) r2 = 8
  178: (85) call 4
  179: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  180: (bf) r1 = r10
  181: (07) r1 += -72
  182: (bf) r2 = r8
  183: (85) call 4
  184: (b7) r1 = 64
  185: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -248)
  186: (0f) r3 += r1
  187: (bf) r1 = r10
  188: (07) r1 += -200
  189: (b7) r2 = 8
  190: (85) call 4
  191: (b7) r1 = 2812
  192: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -200)
  193: (0f) r3 += r1
  194: (bf) r6 = r10
  195: (07) r6 += -216
  196: (bf) r1 = r6
  197: (b7) r2 = 16
  198: (85) call 4
  199: (bf) r1 = r10
  200: (07) r1 += -152
  201: (b7) r2 = 16
  202: (bf) r3 = r6
  203: (85) call 4
  204: (bf) r4 = r10
  205: (07) r4 += -184
  206: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r10 -240)
  207: (18) r2 = 0xffff8806eb930800
  209: (18) r3 = 0xffffffff
  211: (b7) r5 = 184
  212: (85) call 25
  213: (b7) r0 = 0
  214: (95) exit

  from 145 to 147: R0=inv,min_value=0,max_value=0 R1=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R6=imm63,min_value=63,max_value=63 R7=inv,min_value=0,max_value=62 R8=imm0,min_value=0,max_value=0 R9=inv R10=fp fp-240=ctx
  147: (bf) r8 = r7
  148: (b7) r9 = 2136
  149: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -232)
  150: (0f) r3 += r9
  151: (bf) r1 = r10
  152: (07) r1 += -200
  153: (b7) r2 = 8
  154: (85) call 4
  155: (b7) r7 = 296
  156: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -200)
  157: (0f) r3 += r7
  158: (bf) r1 = r10
  159: (07) r1 += -216
  160: (b7) r2 = 8
  161: (85) call 4
  162: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  163: (bf) r1 = r10
  164: (07) r1 += -136
  165: (bf) r2 = r6
  166: (85) call 4
  167: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -224)
  168: (0f) r3 += r9
  169: (bf) r1 = r10
  170: (07) r1 += -200
  171: (b7) r2 = 8
  172: (85) call 4
  173: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -200)
  174: (0f) r3 += r7
  175: (bf) r1 = r10
  176: (07) r1 += -216
  177: (b7) r2 = 8
  178: (85) call 4
  179: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -216)
  180: (bf) r1 = r10
  181: (07) r1 += -72
  182: (bf) r2 = r8
  183: (85) call 4
  R2 type=inv expected=imm
```

I tried replace bpf_probe_read_user with bpf_probe_read